# Xcode error when using tap gesture recognizer

Tags: ios, swift

I start following the Swift tutorial offerred by Apple. In one step using the tap gesture recognizer. When tapping the image, should link to the photoLibrary. But instead, the following message show:

[image]

I have used the sample code by the official answer and the same problem pops up. So I guess it is not the code issue?

Comment: put the code here

Comment: it says app kill by the threading problem, may be you block main thread, do it with background thread or show code you write for gesture.

Comment: Something is wrong with your code.

Comment: The red line means your app is crashed. The image you have posted will not reflect the actual error, Instead please upload image of your debugger . And while asking question if you are not sure what causing the issue it will be better to put code too..so we can see what you have done so far.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleTap:"))
tap.delegate = self
myView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

Then, you should implement the handler, which will be called each time when a tap event occurs:

```
func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
    // handling code
}
```

So now calling your tap gesture recognizer event handler is as easy as calling a method `handleTap()`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but if the error is because of tap gesture. You can try that :

```
let enableTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTap(_:)))

view.addGestureRecognizer(enableTap)

view.userInteractionEnabled = true

 func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
     print("Success!!!")
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

## My code: (sorry it is too long for replying in comment)

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

```
// MARK: Properties

@IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var mealNameLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var photoImageView: UIImageView!


override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Handle the text field’s user input through delegate callbacks.
    nameTextField.delegate = self
}

/*override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() 
 {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
} */




// MARK: UITextFieldDelegate

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool
{
    // Hide the keyboard.
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField)
{
    mealNameLabel.text = textField.text
}



// MARK: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController)
{
    // Dismiss the picker if the user canceled.
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
{
    // The info dictionary may contain multiple representations of the image. You want to use the original.
    guard let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    else
    {
        fatalError("Expected a dictionary containing an image, but was provided the following: \(info)")
    }

    // Set photoImageView to display the selected image.
    photoImageView.image = selectedImage

    // Dismiss the picker
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}




// MARK: Actions

@IBAction func setDefaultLabelText(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    mealNameLabel.text = "Default Text"
}


@IBAction func selectImageFromPhotoLibrary(_ sender: Any)
{
    // Hide the keyboard
    nameTextField.resignFirstResponder()

    // UIImagePickerController is a view controller that lets a user pick media from their photo library.
    let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()

    // Only allow photos to be picked, not taken.
    imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    // The type of imagePickerController.sourceType is known to be UIImagePickerControllerSourceType, which is an enumeration. This means you can write its value as the abbreviated form .photoLibrary instead of UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary.

    // Make sure ViewController is notified when the user picks an image.
    imagePickerController.delegate = self
    present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

}